# findViewById Returns Null From Inflated Layout

Tags: android, android-layout

We're in a situation where we are trying to display an error message when an activity might be destroyed before the error message is displayed (i.e. firing off an AsyncTask to refresh some data and then finishing the activity). We'd like to display an error message.

Right now we can do with Toast using the application as the context. This works fine.

We're trying to add a custom layout to the mix. We can inflate the layout, and are then attempting to set some of the text views. Unfortunately, when we call findByViewId on the inflated view it's always null and we can't set the text in the custom layout.

Any recommendations on a good way to approach this? The only reference we have at that point is the Application.

Comment: Make sure the view exists before trying to use findViewById.  Is the custom layout done programmaticaly or xml?

Comment: The issue seems to be that the content isn't set yet and we can't get the view without the content being set. As this is a base class and happens before then there is no way to know what the resulting content would be.

Comment: @Phobos That's correct it's done with XML. I suppose if we just go a code approach it would be fine.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes XML layouts (the resulting "R.*" files more precisely) gets out of sync with the project and this leads to problems like yours. The cure is to "clean" (`Project` -> `Clean` from eclipse main menu) the project and start the app again.